# How to use preferences within a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, preferences

I have the following problem.
I am implementing a sliding menu from [jfeinstein10](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) and for each menu option, I give a call to a different fragment class. In my menu options, I have a choice called profile in which when clicked, I want a new fragment with preferences to be displayed. Normally, I can do this by using PreferenceFragment, but that does not work with the sliding menu as it expects a class of type Fragment.

Here is my COde on Item click.

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        Fragment newContent = null;

        Class<?> cls = null;
        switch (position) {

        case 0:  /*this is the one that I want to edit*/
            newContent = new profileFragment();
            break;
        }
        if (newContent != null)
            switchFragment(newContent);


    }
```

How can I show the preferences in a Fragment?
Normally I would do this:

```
public class profileFragment extends PreferenceFragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }       
}
```

But that doesnt work as it extends PreferenceFragment and not Fragment
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you actually tried extending `PreferenceFragment` in place of `Fragment`?

Comment: Yes, but the sliding menu accepts a fragment as input, it does not recognize Preference Fragment. If you see in the onItemClick I have Fragment newContent = null;